# How to link content to buttons on Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

Below is a screenshot of the buttons that I want to take action when pressed when my program runs.

How can I make this work?

[image: [Screenshot]]

Answer (score 0):

Just press control button from your keyboard and do the following:

[image]

And write your code into that action and it will run when you press the button at run time.

Comment: What I wanted to know is that if you run an app and the apps gives you clickables options while running, how do you make those options linked

Comment: Do same for all the buttons

Comment: How to link content to clickable options on X Code. This is a new screenshot of the clickable options that I want to take action while my program is running. Can someone please help me find out how I can make this work?  http://i.imgur.com/8koe4ob